# Firebase Display Data from Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
<button id="all" onclick="button()"> View All </button>

<script>
  function button(){
    var userRef = new Firebase("https://addview-c21e6.firebaseio.com/users/");
    userRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
      // The callback function will get called twice, once for "fred" and once for "barney"
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        // key will be "fred" the first time and "barney" the second time
        var key = childSnapshot.key();
        // childData will be the actual contents of the child
        var childData = console.log(childSnapshot.val());
        var para = document.createElement("p");
        var node = document.createTextNode(childSnapshot.val());
        para.appendChild(node);
        var element = document.getElementById("viewAll");
        element.appendChild(para);
      });
    });
  }
</script>
<div id="viewAll"> </div>
```

The above code is what I have for my question. My tree is as follows: I have the root as users, then under that there is the username (i.e. john) and then under that there are two children.. Name and Age. So essentially I want the viewAll div to have all my data in the database be listed. So should list: John 15, Jake 16, and so on until it reaches the last user. At the moment it is just printing object Object. Where do I go from here? P.S. There is more code I'm just not showing it all for simplicity.
I appreciate the help!

Comment: Instead of describing your data structure, please share the actual JSON (as text, no screenshot) which you can get by exporting it from the Firebase Console.

Comment: {
  "users" : {
    "Andy" : {
      "Age" : "12",
      "Name" : "Andy"
    },
    "ada" : {
      "Age" : "11",
      "Name" : "ada"
    },
    "adam" : {
      "Age" : "12",
      "Name" : "adam"
    },
    "dave" : {
      "Age" : "20",
      "Name" : "dave"
    },
    "sam" : {
      "Age" : "15",
      "Name" : "sam"
    },
    "taras" : {
      "Age" : "12",
      "Name" : "taras"
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Your `childSnapshot.val()` should be the JSON object with the username, name and age, assuming each of your user looks something like this:

```
'fred': { username: 'fred', name: 'Fred Flintstone', age: 45 },
'barney': { username: 'barney', name: 'Barney Rubble', age: 44 }
```

In your `forEach()` loop, you should be able to access each of the properties like this:

```
var userInfo = childSnapshot.val();
var username = userInfo.username;
var name = userInfo.name;
var age = userInfo.age;
```

Comment: {
  "users" : {
    "Andy" : {
      "Age" : "12",
      "Name" : "Andy"
    },
    "ada" : {
      "Age" : "11",
      "Name" : "ada"
    },
    "adam" : {
      "Age" : "12",
      "Name" : "adam"
    },
    "dave" : {
      "Age" : "20",
      "Name" : "dave"
    }

Comment: Here is for example, what my database structure where to look like. First is the child of users, then the actual Name, then Name: and Age:

Comment: It won't let me access userInfo.Name before I access for example the user Andy. How do I access Andy without actually knowing his name in the code? Or should I restructure my data?

Comment: @TarasTataryn, you want to use a firebase list to generate your users. One big difference between a firebase list and a JS list/array is that firebase "list" is actually structured to be an object instead of an array but it has child nodes that firebase can sort the list by. [Read about firebase "array" here.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase). FYI you may want to consider using Firebase 3 if you are not too far into your project instead of Firebase 2, which is what your code is based on.

Comment: Planning out your firebase structure will help you a lot down the road. Things you might want to consider are:

1. How do you want to look up your users? username? user id?
2. Do you need to grab a list of users? If so, what order will you need them? Based on name? age?